# rounded corners with plugin to an image in IE 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7, rounded-corners

Finally i convinced to my boss not to use rounded images anymore,

So i want to convert all of them into html with css border-radius. The problem is that we still need support with Internet Explorer 7, and the solution seems to be in this [jquery plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/).

the thing is that in the oficial website works fine with IE even 6. but i can only get it work in Firefox or Chrome (wich is useless cause they already support border-radius)

this is how i'm trying,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.rounded5').corner();
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<img src="http://images.wikia.com/logopedia/images/d/dc/TRYP_by_Wyndham_logo.png" style="width:50%;" alt="trip" class="rounded5" />

</body>

</html>
```

this is the proof http://jsfiddle.net/MKvHu/2/

Any idea what i'm missing?

thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

why don't you try [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not made explicitly clear, but it doesn't look like the plugin can round the edges of `img` elements:

> It's important to understand that this corner plugin is pulling off its magic by adding more elements to the page. Specifically, it adds div "strips" to the item to be cornered and sets a solid background color on these strips in order to hide the actual corners of the real item.

This means that you can only have a rounded *frame of a solid color* around the image using this plugin.

The reason it appears to work in Chrome and Firefox is because they support `border-radius` natively, which *does* work on `img` elements. However, if you change the type of corner to something else like `bevel`, you can see that it is not supported in any browser:
http://jsfiddle.net/namuol/MKvHu/4/

Notice how it works for the `div` below, but not the `img`. So, unfortunately you may want to stick with statically-rounded images if IE7 users *need* images to be rounded.

Comment: woho, he doesn't need to stick to his old solution ... he could combine this plugin with eg following call `$('img').wrap($('<div/>'));` or something alike ... so every image is wrapped by a container, which jquery.corner can use :)

Comment: ...except that would just add a rounded *frame* around the image. That is not what he is looking for.

Comment: arg, you are right ... but that should be possible, by enhancing the `overflow` css-thing with some width- and height-magic :)

Comment: That's an interesting idea, actually.